# How do I retrieve a syntax file (nginx.vim) and load it in vim?

Tags: nginx, vim, nginx-config

On one of my Ubuntu computers, Vim has syntax highlighting for nginx config files while it does not on the other one. Looking at `/usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/` I see one has `nginx.vim` while the other does not. Is there a simple command or repository I can use to retrieve and install syntax highlighting for nginx config files?

Comment: @Friedrich On Debian the file belongs to `vim-runtime` package so it must be installed with `vim`, `vim-tiny`, `vim-gui`, whatever.

Comment: @phd I can never keep track of those dependencies so I looked it up. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian-based distros have a long-standing tradition of separating Vim into several packages to 1) save a couple of megabytes and 2) annoy their users.

Assuming it's Ubuntu 22 you're using (the question doesn't say but it should be the same for other versions), the syntax file for `nginx` is part of the package [`vim-runtime`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/all/vim-runtime/filelist). The more complete GUI versions of Vim like [`vim-gtk3`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/vim-gtk3) depend on `vim-runtime` while the smaller [`vim-tiny`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/vim-tiny) does not.

It has become one of my first steps on any Debian-based system to do

```bash
sudo apt-get install vim-gtk3
```

The amount of features pays off quickly even if the actual GUI version  is never used.

This answers the first part of the question ("how to retrieve"), the second part ("load it in Vim") should be done automatically when Vim opens a file it detects to have `filetype=nginx`.